# Find the playlists where all the tracks are by the same composer with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

1. Playlist (PlaylistId, Name)
2. PlaylistTrack(PlaylistId, TrackId)
3. Track(TrackId, Name, Composer)

I have to find all playlist ids where all the tracks are by the same composer?

I tried this query, but the answer was not correct:

```
SELECT P.PlaylistId
FROM PlatList P , PlaylistTrack PT
WHERE P.PlaylistId = PT.PlaylistID AND PT.TrackId = (SELECT T1.TrackId
                                                     FROM Track T1, Track T2
                                                     WHERE T1.Composer = T2.Composer)
GROUP BY P.PlaylistId
```

Comment: School work? GROUP BY combined with HAVING COUNT DISTINCT can be used. Or NOT EXISTS.

Comment: where the composeid?

Comment: Alternatively, find playlists where no track is not by the same composer.

Comment: theres no composerid

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: i tried a number of queries but without any result :/

Comment: include your tried query in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter with the `HAVING` clause every playlist that has more than one composer.

```
SELECT
p.PlaylistId
FROM
Playlist p
JOIN PlaylistTrack pt ON p.PlaylistId = pt.PlaylistId
JOIN Track t ON pt.TrackId = t.TrackId
GROUP BY p.PlaylistId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Composer) = 1;
```

And use the `JOIN` clause to join tables, not the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: why joining tables by JOIN is better than joining at the WHERE clause?

Comment: Well, first of all, it's more readable and less error prone. That's because it became standard in 1992. Second, it's less complicated for certain joins. For a `LEFT JOIN` I obviously just add the word `LEFT`. How much do you have to add to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.PlaylisId
FROM Playlist P, PlaylistTrack PT, Track T
WHERE P.PlaylistId = PT.PlaylistId , PT.TrackId = T.TrackId
GROUP BY P.PlaylistId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T.Composer) =1
```

Comment: Your answer has syntax errors and adds nothing new to my answer. Please have a look at the [quick tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you don't know how this site works. Thanks.